# How get CheckBox value from ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, aspxgridview

I've ASPxGridView with data from Data Base. I've add one column with CheckBox yet.
And I'm have button with action onClick. I'm want when i press button was performed  this code

```
GridViewDataColumn dataColumn = ASPxGridView1.Columns[3] as GridViewDataColumn;

        for (int i=0;i<ASPxGridView1.VisibleRowCount;i++)
        {
            DataRow row = ASPxGridView1.GetDataRow(i);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update Student set Enable=" + (Convert.ToBoolean(row["Enable"]) ? "0" : "1") + " where id=" + row["id"].ToString(), connection);
            ASPxCheckBox box = ASPxGridView1.FindRowCellTemplateControl(i, dataColumn, "cb") as ASPxCheckBox;
            if (box!=null && box.Checked)
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
```

But variable Box always have checked false. Even when CheckBox should matter true.  This ASPxGridView

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="id" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0">
                    <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="FName" VisibleIndex="2">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="LName" VisibleIndex="3">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="#" VisibleIndex="1">
                <DataItemTemplate>
                    <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="cb" runat="server" >
                    </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
                </DataItemTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Phone" VisibleIndex="5">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Email" VisibleIndex="6">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn FieldName="Enable" Visible="False" VisibleIndex="7" Name="Enable">
                </dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn>
            </Columns>
        </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

I'll want  to mark the necessary rows and updat table if box.checked=true.
How this doing another way i'm don’t understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After row `DataRow row = ASPxGridView1.GetDataRow(i)` all checkBoks become false, because on second cicle `if` false.